How can I reproject a feature class without losing it's archive history
We have an enterprise geodatabase with a number of feature classes that we'd like to reproject to web mercator, but ArcGIS Pro's project tool creates a separate feature class, you can't overwrite or simply just change a layer's projection. Because the tool exports feature class to feature class you lose the original FC's archive history.
I'm looking for a way to either change a feature classes projection without exporting it, or retain its archive history after exporting it to a new prpjection.
I've tried every projection tool I can find and I thought I had success with the "define projection" tool, but this tool didn't actually change the geometry of the layer and so when trying to calculate geometry it skipped every feature due to null geometry. I've also tried playing with the archiving settings but haven't had any luck and am surprised to find very little online regarding this issue.
